# React Native - How to implement Instagram like autocomplete search input tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was playing around with instagram, and I discovered this cool feature in their messaging wherein you can seach for people in a text input, and the text input will auto suggest the top suggestion in a way that it creates a clickable tag inside the text input which allows you to tap it to select the person, and also while you're typing it completes the tag suggestion. Here's a gif to show you better how it works:

Anyone who can provide a simple explanation on how the typing while a tag suggestion is showing works will be much appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but it should be a state or reducer that save the text, and it has to be defined in that textInput onChange event  to call an API repeatedly,

Comment: My question is how do you implement this kind of behavior in React Native wherein a textinput can have a tag that can be inputted inside it